# Can I use simulink to control a robot in Webbots 2019a？

Tags: matlab, simulink, webots

I have made a robot in webots 2019a and it can run with c controller. But if I want control the robot in simulink, how to do it? I can't find any Tutorials from Official document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option is to take a look at the MATLAB support: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-matlab

Moreover, an alternative option might be using the ROS Webots controller and the ROS support of Simulink.

Another option is to use a messaging library such as ZeroMQ, for example, to send the data from Simulink to the Webots. This blog article outlines the procedure: https://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2018/05/01/communicating-with-an-external-application-for-co-simulation/

Comment: I want to use Simulink of MATLAB to calculate the foot trajectory and send the data to Webots to execute. Meanwhile, Webots send the data which measurd by sensors in robot to Simulink and modify the controller. Can I realize it? Is there a more simple way?